# Universe : SQL Statement with dates to YYYYMMDD string

Tags: sql, date, universe

I am trying to do that kind of SQL query on a Universe Rocket U2 System:

```
SELECT id
FROM bars
WHERE DATE() BETWEEN DATE(starting_date) - 3 AND DATE(ending_date) + 3;
```

However, my starting_date and my ending_date are stored in "YYYYMMDD" strings, I can't make that query works, I'm unable to find date functions allowing me to do that.
I've found CURRENT_DATE replacing DATE() but I can't find how to convert my YYYYMMDD to dates.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse a date from unformatted text in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411072/parse-a-date-from-unformatted-text-in-sql)

Comment: Unfortunately, only CAST date function works but converts from internal date to our date and not the opposite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This RetrieVe expression will return the current date as YYYYMMDD.

```
OCONV(@DATE, "DYMD[,2,2]"); FIELD(@1, " ", 1):FIELD(@1, " ", 2):FIELD(@1, " ", 3)
```

Note I have added the format to include the month and day as two digits, something I missed in the SQL of my first post. Four digits is the default for Year so it can be omitted but the comma is required for holding the place.

BTW If you ever need the current date as YYYY-MM-DD the CONV format is:

```
D-YMD[,2,2]
```

(Any non-numeric character can be used in the location of the dash.)

You can include ad hoc RetrieVe expressions in SQL by using EVAL.

```
SELECT EVAL 'OCONV(@DATE, "DYMD[,2,2]"); FIELD(@1, " ", 1):FIELD(@1, " ", 2):FIELD(@1, " ", 3)' AS alias FROM sometable
```

To use EVAL in a WHERE clause you need to select and alias it then refer to the alias in the WHERE clause.

Comment: According to the documentation, the format default for D and M should include the leading zeroes which can be suppressed by using Z as the format "DYMD[,Z,Z]". However the zeroes were suppressed when I ran it against dates in a table so I added the format.

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks for your help, that's some things I didn't know I could use (discovering this legacy in my company, i'm a young developper, not used at all to that !)

Comment: I can promise you there are many more things to know about Universe. It is a very odd beast, especially when you get into the multivalue aspects, particularly for SQL UPDATE and INSERT. Check out my post about using UniverseSQL with multivalues if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641646/u2-universe-update-a-multivalue-field/76369621#76369621 . I also have a post on here about the capabilities of working with Universe as a Linked Server inside MS SQL Server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378469/library-to-read-rocket-u2-data/76537265#76537265 .

Comment: http://www.mannyneira.com/universe/ is worth reading for information about the database structure, using ED and RetrieVe, though the author wrongly eschews the use of UniverseSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some leads. Have not got time to work it all out right now.

This will express CURRENT_DATE as YYYY MM DD

```
CURRENT_DATE CONV 'DYMD'
```

The SUBSTRING function will return parts of a string.

```
SUBSTRING('starting_date' FROM 1 FOR 4)
```

The Universe SQL concatenation operator is a double pipe

```
||
```

Better to convert CURRENT_DATE to YYYYMMDD as this will avoid having to process every record in the table.

You would have a better time working with the more powerful RetrieVe expressions.
I'll come back with that tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I learned something ! I made a workaround by creating descriptors converting dates in the format I wished and I use these in my SQL statement, however I'm still very interested by a way to do it without that much workaround !
I was unable to find an easy convert to "YYYYMMDD" with CONV from reading IBM documentations, do I need to concatenate YYYY then MM then DD to have a clean format ?